# How to load popover in swift

Tags: swift, popover

I am trying to get a popover working in swift.

The view i am trying to put into the popover is in its own separate xib.

The code to load is below

```
    let view = OrganisationDetails()
    view.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    let popoverMenuViewController = view.popoverPresentationController
    view.preferredContentSize =  CGSizeMake(550,550)
    popoverMenuViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverMenuViewController?.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceView = sender
    popoverMenuViewController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: 60, height: 60)
    presentViewController(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What is happening atm is the popover is loading totally blank and not displaying the view.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is much simpler than that. In the storyboard you should make the viewcontroller you want to use as popover and make a viewcontroller class for it as usual. Make a segue as shown below from the object you want to open the popover, in this case the UIBarButton named "Config".

[image]

In the "mother viewcontroller" implement the "UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate" and the delegate method:

```
func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
    //do som stuff from the popover
}
```

Override the "prepareForSeque" method like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     //segue for the popover configuration window
    if segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifierForPopOver" {
        if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? UIViewController {
            controller.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
            controller.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 320, height: 186)
        }
    }
}
```

And your done. And you can now treat the popover view as any other view, ie. add fields and what not!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it

```
    //MARK:idPopupFileTable
    let popoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("idPopupFileTable") as UIViewController
    popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    popoverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 200)

    if let popoverController = popoverVC.popoverPresentationController {
      popoverController.sourceView = sender
      popoverController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
      popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = .Any

      popoverController.delegate = self
    }
    presentViewController(popoverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

  }
```